# 'X' is not a template type but in the MCVE it compiles fine

Tags: c++11, templates

I decided to change a class in my code to become a template. This came up with the `'X' is not a template type` error no matter what I changed.  In the end I rolled back the changes and made the simplest change possible: I put `template <typename T>` in front of the class so I had:

```
template <typename T>
class X
{
...
```

Still get the error.

So I made a MCVE but that works fine.

Why does that one additional line cause an error?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class A
{
};

template <class D>
class S : public D
{
};

template <class T> // line 13
class OM
{
public:
    explicit OM(int a, int b , int c)
    {
        std::cout << "OM ctor\n";
        std::cout << "a = " << a << " , b = " << b << " , c = " << c << " \n";
    }
    std::vector<A> v;
};

int main(int, const char*[])
{
    OM om(1,2,3);    
    //OM<S<A>> om(1,2,3); // line 28   
}
```

In the MCVE above, if line 13 is commented out the code compiles, but left in gives a `missing template arguments before 'om'` error, not `'X' is not a template type` like I get in the full program.  Line 28 is where I want to get to and I can easily modify the MCVE to achieve that.

Comment: If `OM` is a template, you can't use it as a type. Try, for example, `OM<int>` (in the main function)

Comment: In the real application it will be used similar to how it is demonstrated on line 28.  The issue I am having is that I get two different errors if I add a single line of code.

Comment: Also, it's not really an MCVE if it does not demonstrate the problem at hand.

Comment: I wrote the MCVE to get a reproducible error. I didn't, so now I want to know why adding 1 line of code can cause a failure.

Comment: This question essentially asks us to play a guessing game. In the code given, the problem is that you are using a template as a type. In the code you have not shown us, the problem is ... I'm guessing missing semicolon.

Comment: I said I put `template <typename T>` in front of class X and I get the error saying `‘X’ is not a template type`. Take out that line of code and everything compiles perfectly. There is no way I can put a two thousand line class on here especially when I has objects passed in (logging class and io_service) will just confuse things further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an MCVE that demonstrates the original issue:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class OM;

class BH
{
public:
    BH(OM& om): om_(om) { std::cout << "BH ctor\n"; }
    OM& om_;
};


class A
{
};

template <class D>
class S : public D
{
};

template <class T> // line 23
class OM
{
public:
    explicit OM(int a, int b , int c)
    {
        std::cout << "OM ctor\n";
        std::cout << "a = " << a << " , b = " << b << " , c = " << c << " \n";
    }
    std::vector<A> v;
};

int main(int, const char*[])
{
    OM om(1,2,3);    
    //OM<S<A>> om(1,2,3); // line 38
    BH bh(om);
}

template_test.cpp:24:7: error: ‘OM’ is not a template type
 class OM
       ^
```

Which proves it is the forward declaration that is the issue but the original compilation never pointed that out. I now need to weigh up changing every forward declaration and every class to support which I suspect might mean moving every cpp implementation into the header file...

So the issue is a really poor error message - if it pointed out where it had been declared differently then I might of realised the issue sooner.

Comment: A simple fix for your first issue (changing all forward declarations) is to use forward declaration headers. Of course, at this point in time that doesn't really help reduce the amount of work you'll have to do :).

Comment: This is why they invented grep and sed! :-)

Comment: I would say that the error message is programmer speak for "I already know this is not a template". It could be clearer.